# how to map escape key in vim to dismiss coc pop up menu?

Tags: vim

I have remapped the tab key to select an item from the COC popup menu

```
inoremap <expr><TAB> pumvisible() ? coc#_select_confirm() : "\<TAB>"
```

this works fine, but:

I also want the escape key to dismiss the menu on the first key press, then exit insert mode on the second key press.
I tried using this very similar mapping config...

```
inoremap <expr><ESC> pumvisible() ? coc#pum#cancel() : "\<ESC>"
```

but this always exits insert mode immediately, as if `pumvisible()` is always returning false

why doesn't it work? and how do I make it work?

Comment: You didn't "remap" `<Tab>`, you *mapped* it. Anyway, does it still happen with `$ vim -Nu NONE` and/or `$ vim --clean`? If not, can we see your `vimrc`? Working hypothesis: a timeout issue.

Comment: I don't care much for your nit picking about mapping versus remapping given you haven't explained why it matters here.

Comment: It matters in general. Now, how about answers?